# 'dict' object has no attribute 'texts_to_sequences' error when i use seq= tokenizer.texts_to_sequences([txt])

Tags: keras, lstm, tokenize, predict

i tried several ways but i get the same error so i tried the same as https://androidkt.com/saved-keras-model-to-predict-text-from-scratch/

```
txt="السلام عليكم"
seq= loaded_tokenizer.texts_to_sequences([txt])
padded = pad_sequences(seq, maxlen=max_len)
pred = model.predict_classes(padded)
print(pred)
```

this is how i loaded the tokenizer

```
with open('pic2.pickle', 'rb') as handle:
     loaded_tokenizer = pickle.load(handle)
```

this is my first time working with text models and i am not sure how to solve this issue

Comment: your loaded file is stored in `loaded_tokenizer` but your text_to_sequences is being called on `tokenizer`

Comment: @ML_Engine yes thank you for looking at my problem, but i checked this already and still the same error appears

Comment: Please can you post the rest of your code? Specifically where you are creating, fitting and saving the tokenizer. Thanks